# BackGroundWorker is not working properly

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, telerik, wpf-controls, backgroundworker

I am using System.ComponentModel.BackGroundWorker in my WPF application.
So, what i am doing is as fllowing

" **I have a file browser control and two buttons called import and cancel on a wpf dialog 
  when user selects a file with the help of file browser control and clicks on import button
  ,then since application has to read data from a large text file,therefore i am displaying telerik busy indicator until file is loaded,So what i do when file path is selected**

Creates a background worker and assign do_work handler

```
this.backgroundWorkerThread = new BackgroundWorker
    {
      WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
    };
    // when the thread gets starts, call the function to be executed
    this.backgroundWorkerThread.DoWork += (sender,
                                           do_workArgs) =>
    {
      // import all scenarios
      do_workArgs.Result = this.ImportScenarios();
    };
```

and calls 
   this.backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync()

and when user clicks the cancel button then i do following thing:

```
 if (
          (this.backgroundWorkerThread != null)
          &&
          (this.backgroundWorkerThread.IsBusy)
         )
      {
        this.backgroundWorkerThread.CancelAsync();
      }
```

**Issue** :

this close actually dispose the background worker but in do worker method, method assigned in the args.result = import()Scenarios() is not terminated, it continues, so what i am looking for is that when i click the cancel button the whole process should be terminated. in my case only background worker is disposed but assigned method in do worked event handler is not aborted, so i want to abort the method as well as. Can anybody suggest me the possible solution

Comment: Aborting a thread is fundamentally dangerous operation.  You need to check in the worker whether it's been cancelled.

Comment: You must check background worker state inside `ImportScenarios`. If backgroundworker has been cancelled, return the function asap

Comment: when i will check the background worker state in ImportScenarios()
for example if(this.backgroundworker.CancellatinPending), then in case cancel has been click then backgroundwoker would be null. in import scenarios